# Using derived table to group by ALIAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help rewriting the following query as I need to group by the aliases and derived tables appear to be the only path open to me. I cannot group by Type and SalesDatabase as I get an invalid column error.

```
SELECT    'Transactions'        AS Type,  
          'SalesDb'             AS SalesDatabase,  
          COUNT (B.Id)          AS Total,  
          CASE 
              WHEN SB.name LIKE '%Online%'      THEN 'Online'   
              WHEN SB.name LIKE '%RetailSale%'  THEN 'Retail'   
              ELSE 'Bricks'   
          END AS SalesType,    
          ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN datediff( d, b.Inserted, getDate() ) <  1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS SalesPeriod0,          
          ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN datediff( d, b.Inserted, getDate() ) >=  1 and datediff( d, b.Inserted, getDate() ) < 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS SalesPeriod1to7 ,         
          ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN datediff( d, b.Inserted, getDate() ) >= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS SalesPeriod8p  
FROM SalesItem B WITH (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN SalesBatch SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.Id  = B.BatchId    
GROUP BY SB.NAME
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For one, please stop using `AS 'alias'` - use `AS [alias]` or just `AS alias`

Comment: Why do you need to group by Type and SalesDatabase? They're constants and essentially useless in terms of grouping (every single row has the same value). Did you mean you need to group by SalesType? You have two solutions: (a) use a derived table (b) repeat the expression.

Comment: @Aaron: no comment on `NOLOCK`?

Comment: Type and SalesDatabase are columns that I need to be present. They are visible in order to group the results as this is a single select that will be unioned with another SalesDatabase. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Here are a few ways to do this (and yes, @ypercube, I knock NOLOCK there): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d73f/3

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it works like a charm. Just wondering why you guys are knocking NOLOCK hint so much? It has been hammered into me at work to include it in every single query. What alternatives exist?

Comment: WOW, have not seen sqlfiddle before. What a bastion of knowledge stackoverflow can be with such a great userbase!!

Comment: The alternative is not to use it.

Comment: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` is equivalent to NOLOCK-everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query as you have written is correct, if you intend to produce one row PER SB.NAME.  It means that you could have

```
SB.NAME    | SalesType   | ...
ABC        | Online      | ...
DEF        | Online      | ...
XYZ        | Retail      | ...
DEF1       | Retail      | ...
```

However, if you want to group by SalesType, then use this GROUP BY

```
GROUP BY CASE 
          WHEN SB.name LIKE '%Online%'      THEN 'Online'   
          WHEN SB.name LIKE '%RetailSale%'  THEN 'Retail'   
          ELSE 'Bricks'   
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for grouping the constants Type and SalesDatabase.

```
GROUP BY SB.NAME,  
          CASE 
              WHEN SB.name LIKE '%Online%'      THEN 'Online'   
              WHEN SB.name LIKE '%RetailSale%'  THEN 'Retail'   
              ELSE 'Bricks'   
          END
```